# Wordpress Thesis: Tweetmeme button remains after we got rid of the plugin

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

We are having problems with getting rid of a Tweetmeme button from our Wordpress thesis blog.
The button somehow remains after we removed the plugin.

First we installed the plugin to the blog, but since we had problems, we asked our developer to fix the issue (He did something to the code of the plugin). After that, we switched to the official Tweet button and removed the Tweetmeme plugin.

When we see the source of a blog post, there is a Tweetmeme code there.
How can we get rid of the button/code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that he just hard coded the button into your theme. Look for 'tweetmeme' in your theme's `.php` files.